# Using Javascript to go to a sub url and then a specific section id within that url

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble making this work.

I want to use javascript to change to a sub url and then go to a specific section id as well.

This is what I'm using:

Javascript:

```
'click .acq-click'(event) {
    location.href = '/products#acquisition';
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="acquisition">
some html
</section>
```

However, when I click the button, it takes me to the sub url with this hash, but it won't move to that section id.  It loads at the top of the page.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean section id?

Comment: Please show us the HTML of the target page and how you are defining the `acquisition` location.

Comment: I added it, it's simple.  Just a section with an id.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an anchor and a link to it:

Place this somewhere where you want to go to:

```
<a name="anchor"></a>
```

Then you can link to this position like this:

```
<a href="#anchor">Go to Anchor</a>
```

Comment: First of all, the anchor is an id, not a name.  And second, I already have this.